# Can RUP (Rational Unified Process) be used in one-man project?

Tags: rup

Is it an obligation to have actual team (more than 1 person) to use RUP or can be RUP schema followed by only one man? Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [Rational Unified Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Unified_Process) in a one-person team? While I suppose it might be a hint about the sorts of things that you're going to have to do, it would seem to me to be an absurdly heavyweight thing to use formally. Like using a thermonuclear weapon to kill a mosquito, it will work but is still Doing It Wrong.

For a single person team, [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) is almost certainly a better choice, as it helps you focus on being immediately productive (and hence on staying motivated, the big long-term problem). You don't need a great deal more than that because you don't have to worry about problems like lack of communication between development teams…

Comment: Great example with mosquito, I'll think about it. Thanks

Comment: +1 for "using a thermonuclear weapon to kill a mosquito"

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be reasonable if you cannot estabilish a team for trying out a process. But practically, you would certainly want to adjust it to remove artifacts, which are used for communication, which you will not need. You should also bear in mind, that it might be hard to act objectively especially in testing and all other review activities.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion (dakujem za nazor :))

Comment: @Xorty No problem:) (BTW. poznáme sa? Zaujímalo by ma aké máš úmysly s tm RUP-om, ak chceš vyskúšať, veľmi rád by som sa pridal.)

Comment: just a bachelor thesis atm :) And no, we don't know each other I think (inymi slovami, mal som nieco dokazat na bakalarke, ale nemyslim si, ze to s tym RUPom ma zmysel pre jedneho cloveka, kopec principov som ignoroval)

Comment: @Xorty thank you. These comments are off topic, so I will remove all mine

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you can use RUP in "one"  man project...:-)

Just look at it:

Kruchten, **"A Software Development Process for a Team of One"**

Read Online at : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/feb02/ProcessForOneFeb02.pdf